# Oracle procedure causing InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I'm using C# with a Oracle Database and trying to call a procedure with parameters that returns me a cursor. The trouble here is that when I add a parameter, in my very first statement, I receive the following:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code
```

I have the following method:

```
public void PrintLabel()
{
    IDbConnection conn = _connection;
    using (IDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "PROC_0019";
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_id_template", OracleDbType.Double, 1000, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = 6);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_id_proc", OracleDbType.Double, 1000, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = 3);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_id_input", OracleDbType.Double, 1000, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = 232905);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_tips", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1000, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "BLANK");
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_start", OracleDbType.Double, 1000, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = 1);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_all", OracleDbType.Double, 1000, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = 1);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_newtemplate", OracleDbType.Clob).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output);
    }
}
```

Am I giving the incorrect argument for `*.Parameters.Add()`?

Comment: have you solved this issue ?